# Cannot find resouce named IntToImageConvert

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, resourcedictionary

I am trying to convert a property byte into image depending on number. I have a named IntToImageConverter. It works from usercontrol but not with resourcedictionary. I think it has to do with the communication between the resourcedictionary and the convertclass. Because i can bind the statusID through text but not through image.
rep is instance of usercontrol
mycanvas name of the canvas

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Prototype.Models">

        <local:IntToImageConvert x:Key="convert"/>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ShapeTS">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <local:IntToImageConvert x:Key="convert"></local:IntToImageConvert>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Image  Source="/assets/item.png" Stretch="Uniform" Width="20" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Image Height="20" Width="20" Source="{Binding StatusID, Converter={StaticResource convert}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Image>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Title,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="8px"/>
        <Expander>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="ObjectID: "></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjectID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="8px"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="  "></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="RelatedOBjectID: "></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelatedObjectID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="8px"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="StartTime:"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="8px"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="RowsInserted:"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RowsInserted, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="8px"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="ExecutionTime"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ExecutionTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="8px"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

C#

```
tblLvl1 = new TableObjects(
        Application.Current.Resources["ShapeTS"] as ControlTemplate,
        DependencyList[i].ObjectName,
        "/assets/item.png",
        positionLvl1,
        rep.OnDragDelta,
        DependencyList[j].ID,
        DependencyList[j].RelatedObjectID, 
        DependencyList[j].StartTime, 
        DependencyList[j].RowsInserted, 
        DependencyList[j].ExecutionTime, 
        DependencyList[i].StatusID, 
        DependencyList[i].X, 
        DependencyList[i].Y, 
        DependencyList[i].Level);

tblLvl1.DataContext = tblLvl1;
rep.mycanvas.Children.Add(tblLvl1);
```

XAML

```
<Canvas Name="mycanvas">
    <Canvas>
        <Path Stroke="#FF2062A3" StrokeThickness="3">
            <Path.Data>
                <GeometryGroup x:Name="connection"></GeometryGroup>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Maybe your UserControl and that ResourceDictionary aren't in same namespace, and thats why not same local xmlns cant be used.

Comment: Could you show us the `UserControl` `XAML`? Just the opening and resource tags and of course where you can successfully use the converter.

Comment: Putting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on bindings to properties of read-only controls will have no effect on anything.